# In BaseAdapter setVisibility(View.GONE); is not hiding the view but space is released

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, listviewitem

In my BaseAdpater I'm setting the visibility of a view to GONE in a row after some operation. All operation is fine but view remains visible in background while lower views are move up until i touch the screen. It means listview is updating the views and releasing the space on setting visibility to GONE but view is still visible in background. What could be the issue?

Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.iu.foodbucket.BaseActivity;
import com.iu.foodbucket.R;
import com.iu.foodbucket.database.MyDataSource;
import com.iu.foodbucket.fragments.CartFragment;
import com.iu.foodbucket.models.Cart;
import com.iu.foodbucket.utils.AppGlobal;

import java.util.List;

public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Fragment context;
    List<Cart> data;
    MyDataSource myDataSource;
    boolean isOldOrder;

    public CartAdapter(Fragment ctx, List<Cart> data, boolean orderStatus) {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.data = data;
        this.isOldOrder = orderStatus;
        myDataSource = new MyDataSource(ctx.getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_cart, parent, false);
            holder.title_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
            holder.quantity_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_tv);
            holder.price_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price_tv);
            holder.edit_iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_iv);
            holder.thumbnail_iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_iv);
            holder.editPanel = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editPanel);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title_tv.setText(data.get(position).getMenu().getTitle());
        holder.quantity_tv.setText(context.getString(R.string.quantity_abbr) + " " + data.get(position).getQuantity());


        if (((BaseActivity) context.getActivity()).dataPreference.getIsImageEnabled())
            Glide.with(context.getActivity()).load(data.get(position).getMenu().getThumbnail()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_tag_face).centerCrop().into(holder.thumbnail_iv);

        float price = Float.parseFloat(data.get(position).getMenu().getPrice());
        price = (float) AppGlobal.round(price, 2);

        holder.price_tv.setText(data.get(position).getMenu().getPriceUnit() + " " + price);
        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        holder.edit_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.editPanel.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    holder.editPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    showEditablePanel(finalConvertView, position, holder.editPanel);
                } else {
                    holder.editPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private void showEditablePanel(View v, final int position, final LinearLayout editPanel) {
        final TextView quantity_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantityUpdated_tv);
        final ImageButton minus_btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.minus_btn);
        final ImageButton plus_btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.plus_btn);
        ImageButton update_btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.update_btn);
        ImageButton remove_btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.remove_btn);
        final int[] quantity = {Integer.parseInt(data.get(position).getQuantity())};
        quantity_tv.setText(quantity[0] + "");
        minus_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                quantity[0]--;
                updateViews(quantity[0], minus_btn, quantity_tv);
            }
        });
        plus_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                quantity[0]++;
                updateViews(quantity[0], minus_btn, quantity_tv);
            }
        });
        update_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!isOldOrder)   // update cart item in DB
                    myDataSource.updateCartItem(data.get(position).getMenu().getId(), quantity[0] + "");
                data.get(position).setQuantity(quantity[0] + "");
                editPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                ((CartFragment) context).updateTotalValues();
            }
        });
        remove_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deletionConfirmationDialog(position, editPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    public void deletionConfirmationDialog(final int position, final LinearLayout editPanel) {
        final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context.getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.title_delete));
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.message_confirm_deletion));
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.title_yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                if (!isOldOrder)     // delete cart item from DB
                    myDataSource.deleteCartItem(data.get(position).getMenu().getId());
                editPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                data.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                ((CartFragment) context).updateTotalValues();
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.title_no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
            }
        });
        android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    private void updateViews(int quantity, ImageButton minus_btn, TextView quantity_tv) {
        if (quantity > 1) {
            minus_btn.setEnabled(true);
            minus_btn.setAlpha((float) 1.0);
        } else {
            minus_btn.setEnabled(false);
            minus_btn.setAlpha((float) 0.4);
        }
        quantity_tv.setText(quantity + "");
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title_tv, quantity_tv, price_tv;
        ImageView thumbnail_iv, edit_iv;
        LinearLayout editPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Could you please supply a relevant snippet of your code?

Comment: please check now.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean after setting visiblity gone of a row, that row remains blank and that gap is visible,the better way is to filter the adapter content by using getFilter() to display by excluding that row content and notifyadapter changed.

Comment: I mean that gap is removed and lower items are moved up as well, but behind those views that item still remains visible, unless or until screen is touched or listview is moved